# How do you install avconv on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, avconv

I am trying to install avconv by running the following command, but the library doesn't exist anymore for Ubuntu 18.04.

```
sudo apt-get install avconv
```

It is told on other Ubuntu forums to replace the command by the following :

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

But it doesn't contain libraries that can be used for sk-video

Comment: I am building from the binaries that requires avconv and not ffmeg. How to go about it? Would creating a symlink work in my case? how can i create a symlink?

Comment: A touch confusing... The question is really "Since the avconv package went away with 18.04, where can I find it?"  And the answers are "use ffmeg instead"...  However, avconv seems to do some things that ffmeg can not, so if you need it, then you also need the answer to the original question "from where can I install avconv".

Comment: The history of ffmpeg and avconv is a lurid and fascinating one and worth a read.  The distro pretty much went from ffmpeg to avconv and back to ffmpeg.  And there were some crazy politics behind it as well.   Worth a web search and read if you're really curious - but more to the point, for the vast majority, ffmpeg does everything you need and you can generally just replace 'avconv' with 'ffmpeg' everywhere (as we were pushed to do in the other direction some years back).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

The sub-mentioned command installs all what should be contained within avconv

In fact, the python script used contains a call to avconv. I replaced avconv mnemonic by ffmpeg and it worked.

Comment: Some application will get depressed when you didn't provide them with exactly `avconv` and `avprobe`, you can make them happy by `cd /usr/bin && sudo ln ffmpeg avconv && sudo ln ffmpeg avprobe` after your installation of ffmepg

Comment: @NgSekLong Thank you! This should be part of the answer to make it fully work. I'm on Ubuntu 19.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo apt install -y libav-tools
```

or:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libav-tools
```

Comment: There is no `libav-tools` anymore, reporting from Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 now working avconv installing this package. Thanks!

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libav), Libav is an abandoned project. (the final release was on Feb 2018).

Answer (score 0):

Just use ffmpeg, the commands work the same way:

Eg. $ ffmpeg -i "Audio.mp3" -ss 0 -t 300 First_Half.mp3

Comment: duplicate of the accepted answer